# Why is @font-face not working in iOS safari?

Tags: css, fonts

Attempting to import a font in ttf format, it works on Chrome and Safari on desktop but does not render correctly on iOS Safari. Below is the CSS:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Alarm Clock";
   src: url("../images/alarm-clock.ttf") format("truetype");
}

.number {
   margin-top: 45px;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Alarm Clock', sans-serif;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: #4f4f4f;
}
```